# I would like to update MongoDb document

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

my problem is to update a specific field of the document.
    Let's imagine we have multiple input fields when I am just changing one of the field of the document the rest of them going to be null since I am just updating one of them. Is there any simple way to update one field and the rest field not changed.

> **I can give a switch case or if-else but I do not think it is an
>   appropriate way to solve this kind issue.**

```
updateChr:async ( args: any) => {
      try {

       const data = await Client.findByIdAndUpdate(args.clientId, 
        {$set:
        {
          chronology:{
            status: args.clientInput.status,
            note:args.clientInput.note,
            date: args.clientInput.date,
            file:{
              filename:args.clientInput.file.filename,
              data:args.clientInput.file.data,
              type:args.clientInput.file.type,
              size:args.clientInput.file.size,
            }
            }
        },
      }
      ,{useFindAndModify: false})
       return transformClient(data);
      } catch (err) {
        throw err;
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

So this part right here is what you need to pay attention to:

```
{$set:
        {
          chronology:{
            status: args.clientInput.status,
            note:args.clientInput.note,
            date: args.clientInput.date,
            file:{
              filename:args.clientInput.file.filename,
              data:args.clientInput.file.data,
              type:args.clientInput.file.type,
              size:args.clientInput.file.size,
            }
            }
        },
      }
```

What you're telling mongo is that, no matter what's in those fields now (or even if they don't currently exist), to set their new values to what you are providing. If you're providing a null value, then it will set its new value to null. If you aren't wanting to update things if their new value is null, then you'll need to clean up your data prior to pushing it to mongo. The easiest way to do this is to sanitize the data prior to adding it to the object you're referencing above. Once you've only got the data that actually exists there, then just loop over the data to create the update object for mongo rather than statically setting it like it is here.

Alternatively, if the data that actually should exist in those fields is available at this stage, you could loop over the null values and fill them in with the current values in mongo or whatever they *should* be.

Comment: Yes you are right do you have any real example for this kind situation? I mean how to loop over the data? And wil not it take waste of execution time? For each update data will store old values again and again.

Comment: For status, note, and date, it's easy. Just a simple `Object.entries(args.clientInput).forEach(([key,value])=>{if(value !== null){update[key]= value}})` where update is a preset empty object. However, for "file" it's an all or nothing update since it's a subdocument. If you want to update each entry in file in the same way, you'll have to submit a 2nd request where your update parameter matches to file rather than to the base of the document so it'd be `{'chronology.file': $set: {...file}}`.

Comment: As for execution time, you might lose a few cycles doing it this way, but the only way to avoid that is to provide the existing mongo data to the update function so that it doesn't have to parse through things at all. It can just be `this = new || original`.